# TypeError: dispatch on action execution

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

In this my action the user's log out of my application is exported in react

```
export const logoutUser = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(
      {
        type: LOGOUT_USER
      }
    )
      .then(() => {
        logoutUserSuccess(dispatch, )
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        logoutUserError(err, dispatch)
      })
  }
}

const logoutUserSuccess = (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(
    {
      type: LOGOUT_USER_SUCCESS
    }
  )
  AsyncStorage.removeItem('@token_jwt')
  console.log('saiu')
  Actions.loginScreen()
}

const logoutUserError = (err, dispatch) => {
  dispatch(
    {
      type: LOGOUT_USER_ERROR
    }
  )
  Alert.alert('Erro ao sair da conta')
  console.log(err)
}
```

is my Reducer

```
case LOGOUT_USER:
return {
    ...state
}
        case LOGOUT_USER_SUCCESS:
return {
    INITIAL_STATE
}
        case LOGOUT_USER_ERROR:
return {
    ...state
}
```

is my screen to logout

```
 onLogout() {
      this.props.logoutUser()
  }

const mapStateToProps = state => (
  {
    email: state.Authentication.email
  }
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logoutUser })(Home)
```

The return is the following error

[image: Erro]

I put the email on the mapStateToProps, because I don't know how to leave it blank, what matters to me is the logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a `mapDispatchToProps` function and dispatch the action `logoutUser` from inside the function and pass it as a second argument to `connect`.

In doing so, you can invoke the `LogoutUser` from `mapDispatchToProps` in your `onLogout` function.

```
import {logoutUser} from './youractions.js'

onLogout() {
  this.props.LogoutUser();
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  LogoutUser: () => dispatch(logoutUser()),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: can you explain what is msm error? or better can you spin up a sandbox? So the bug can be traced quickly or if you have a GitHub repo, I can take a look at it.

Comment: When I clicked to log out, this error I placed appears

Comment: The error message is now: TypeError: dispatch(...).then is not a function

Comment: I managed to adjust, in the action instead of being then and catch, I put try and catch and instead of passing the map state to props I passed null, adjust your answer so I can put it as right, because it helped